# Extracting stats for Snowflake commandline

Tags: proxy

I noticed that the Firefox browser plugin tells you the number of users connected through your snowflake instance and the number of users that connected within the last 24 hours.

I was wondering if the same stats can be extracted from the log trail of Snowflakes' docker image. I couldn't find any documentation to interpret those logs. Do I have any option other than reading the entire source code?

PS: There's no tag for snowflake. Can somebody create it?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script exactly for that purpose, see https://gist.github.com/Atrate/be4a7d308549c7a9fe281d2cdf578d21

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am new to snowflake, so I'm guessing a bit.*

Looking at the schema [here](https://snowflake.torproject.org/):

[image]

And looking at my log output, a successful connection seems to look like this:

```
sdp offer successfully received.
Generating answer...
OnDataChannel
Connection successful.
OnOpen channel
connected to relay
[...]
OnClose channel
Traffic throughput (up|down): 110 KB|149 KB -- (512 OnMessages, 508 Sends, over 819 seconds)
copy loop ended
datachannelHandler ends
```

Skimming through the source code, I think that the interesting ones are:

- The ["sdp offer"](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/blob/main/proxy/lib/snowflake.go#L384) message seems to be the offer relayed by the broker (number (2) in the picture).
- ["Generating answer"](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/blob/main/proxy/lib/snowflake.go#L386) would be the answer going back to the broker (number (2) in the picture).
- ["Connection successful"](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/blob/main/proxy/lib/snowflake.go#L490) and and ["OnOpen channel"](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/blob/main/proxy/lib/snowflake.go#L346) seem to mean that the WebRTC connection was initiated (number (4) in the picture).
- ["Connected to relay"](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/blob/main/proxy/lib/snowflake.go#L318) sounds like (5) in the picture.
- I guess that you are mostly interested in the [Throughput summary](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/blob/main/proxy/lib/snowflake.go#L352), which seems to summarize what went through your snowflake instance for a particular client.

I don't know what the Firefox plugin uses exactly, but I could imagine that it counts the number of connections that had a non-zero throughput, i.e. the number of "Traffic throughput" lines in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I made a python script which can read in a Snowflake Log-File and give you a summary:
https://gist.github.com/Allstreamer/0bc711d4d35ddb523df560425da76513

This is probably most usefull for people who use the compiled version not the docker version

Answer (score 0):

I used the script from [@allstreamer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/23127/37366), enhanced it a little bit and added a docker-compose template, so it is easier to set everything up: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/MariusHerget/8e061217ad0fb5709ac498e082903bd7).

It has the following features:

- Docker-compose is pre-configured to use the current directory to save the log file.
- Read in the log file and give you statistics about *number of connections* and *used download/upload bandwidth*.
- Configurable time windows (default: *All time*, *Last 24h* and *Last Week*).

Example output:

> [All time ] Served 2978 People with ↑ 14.941 GB, ↓ 3.0149 GB
>
> [Last 24h ] Served  406 People with ↑  1.7402 GB, ↓ 0.4143 GB
>
> [Last Week] Served 2473 People with ↑ 12.6182 GB, ↓ 2.5372 GB